# how to transform a seq into a tree

Tags: clojure

I have a seq of maps such as the coll below. I want to arrange it in a tree. Each map has a key named :parent which is the :id of the parent. Any hints on how can I do it ?

```
(def coll [{:id 1} 
          {:id 2 :parent 1} 
          {:id 3 :parent 1}
          {:id 4 :parent 2}
          {:id 5 :parent 4}
          {:id 6 :parent 5}
          {:id 7 :parent 5}
          {:id 8 :parent 5}
          {:id 9 :parent 7}])
```

Comment: Do you need this transformation for persistence/serialization? Otherwise you should be trying to do the opposite transformation most of the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it walks like a tree...

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as z])

(defn create-zipper [s]
  (let [g (group-by :parent s)] 
    (z/zipper g #(map :id (g %)) nil (-> nil g first :id))))

(def t (create-zipper coll)) ; using the coll defined in the OP

(-> t z/root)
;=> 1

(-> t z/children)
;=> (2 3)

(-> t z/next z/children)
;=> (4)
```

Note that you may preserve the format of the original nodes (rather than just returning id numbers) by using `#(g (% :id))` as the children and `(first (g nil))` as the root.

You can use [post-order traversal](https://github.com/Raynes/laser/blob/e1beb765cf40564a789fa5d2d5f795e9df724530/src/me/raynes/laser/zip.clj#L17) to build up another representation of the tree if desired.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little solution that uses a sequence comprehension. Hopefully it's readable, but it definitely won't win any awards for performance as it re-filters the list at every level of recursion. I imagine there's an amazingly efficient reduce-based solution possible, but I'm still getting the hang of writing those - hopefully someone else will post one :).

Note - I've returned the whole map for each node, as I wasn't sure exactly what you wanted your tree to look like...

```
(defn make-tree
   ([coll] (let [root (first (remove :parent coll))]
               {:node root :children (make-tree root coll)}))
   ([root coll]
       (for [x coll :when (= (:parent x) (:id root))]
           {:node x :children (make-tree x coll)})))

(pprint (make-tree coll)) 

    {:node {:id 1},
     :children
       ({:node {:parent 1, :id 2},
         :children
           ({:node {:parent 2, :id 4},
             :children
               ({:node {:parent 4, :id 5},
                 :children
                   ({:node {:parent 5, :id 6}, :children ()} 
                    {:node {:parent 5, :id 7},
                     :children ({:node {:parent 7, :id 9}, :children ()})}
                    {:node {:parent 5, :id 8}, :children ()})})})}
    {:node {:parent 1, :id 3}, :children ()})}
```